# Styling the contextual action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

i am using orange  color theme in ma action bar ,In edit Text when user try to do copy,paste it  invokes the contextual action with default blue color background ,it's little weird for users,can i change the background of contextual action bar ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this to your style in your **styles.xml** and use any custom color you would like.

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
```

You can also change the drawables for each icon using similar code.

```
android:actionModeCloseDrawable
android:actionModeCopyDrawable
android:actionModeCutDrawable
android:actionModePasteDrawable
android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable
```

Credit to the tutorial here - http://www.codercowboy.com/2013/07/05/styling-the-contextual-action-bar-actionmode-divider-or-splitter-for-android/
for changing the contextual action bar icons. Which told me that starting with **actionMode** changes the contextual action bar attributes

Comment: Thanks a lot.where did u get this? is this on documentation?

Comment: I found a tutorial here - http://www.codercowboy.com/2013/07/05/styling-the-contextual-action-bar-actionmode-divider-or-splitter-for-android/

talking about changing the icons so I knew that it would start with **acitonMode** and I saw Background was an option, tried it and it worked.

Comment: @Asthme no problem! Unfortunately I did not find any official documentation on it

Comment: I case this doesn't work for you (and still have the white bar with white icons), I found other style to be set that does work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27530844/939781