# how to Customize the Contextual Action Bar using appCompat in material design

Tags: android, material-design, android-actionmode

`MainActivity.java`

I've implemented `MultiChoiceModeListener` in this class and below is the code:

on `listView`:

```
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(MainActivity.this);
listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);


    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
        switch (arg1.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save:

            // Close CAB
            arg0.finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.saveto:


            // Close CAB
            arg0.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
        arg0.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.save_menu, arg1);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
        listadaptor.removeSelection();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode arg0, int arg1, long arg2,
            boolean arg3) {

        final int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
        arg0.setTitle(checkedCount + " "+getResources().getString(R.string.selected));
        listadaptor.toggleSelection(arg1);
    }
```

style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/White</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LStyled.ActionMode</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="LStyled.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HeaderBar">
        <item name="android:background">#009688</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    </style>
```

below is my screenshots:

[image: this is my material design screen]

[image: actionmode material design screen]

you can see both screenshots, in second screenshot, actionmode background is white and text color is also white.. i want to change it to first screenshots color which is in top.

Comment: can you explain why you give downvote to this question.?

Comment: Can't see why is down voted. Up voted.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?

Comment: yeah, below accepted answer.

Comment: @Riser How you got title in white color

Comment: This question has helped me a lot. Now I can put action mode over action bar and keep setMultiChoiceModeListener

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can change the `ActionMode` background through attribute `actionModeStyle`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ....
    ....
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LStyled.ActionMode</item>
</style>

<style name="LStyled.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/color_action_mode_bg</item>
</style>
```

You will of course need to define a color named `color_action_mode_bg`:

```
<color name="color_action_mode_bg">#009688</color>
```

There are other things you can change as well. Example:

```
<item name="titleTextStyle">...</item>
<item name="subtitleTextStyle">...</item>
<item name="height">...</item>
```

To change text color of `SAVE` and `SAVETO`, add the following to `AppTheme.Base`:

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/color_action_mode_text</item>
```

Comment: i tried this also.. check my edited style.xml file. but still not working.

Comment: @MunimJi How do you start this `ActionMode`? Can you share that code? If you use `startActionMode(...)`, you'll need to change that to `startSupportActionMode(...)`.

Comment: check my edited question. i added activity class code.

Comment: @MunimJi This is exactly how I have implemented multiple selection. Do you have multiple values-vXX folders? In that case, try moving `<item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LStyled.ActionMode</item>` from `<style name="AppTheme.Base"......` to `<style name="AppTheme"....`.

Comment: @MunimJi One last try: add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base"` to your `<activity ... />` tag in android-manifest. This will test if your activity is indeed getting the correct theme. If this works, we can trace back to the actual problem.

Comment: did this..still not working.. you want see my whole style.xml file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67224/discussion-between-vikram-and-munimji).

Comment: @Vikram How to get title in white color.. `mode.setTitle("Select Items");`  Select items should be in white color

Comment: @Prabs You should be able to set `<item name="titleTextStyle">...</item>` under `LStyled.ActionMode`. The value provided to `titleTextStyle` will be a style that inherits from `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title`. Inside this style, override `android:textColor` and assign it `@android:color/white`.

Comment: how to change background color and textcolor of overflow menu items in CAB?

Comment: @MihirShah What API version(s) are you working with? And how do you start the action mode?

Comment: ActionMode actionMode = mActivity.startSupportActionMode(this); lollipop 5.1 api

Comment: @MihirShah Ok. What is your activity's parent theme? `Theme.AppCompat`?

Comment: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style> <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LStyled.ActionMode</item></style>

Comment: <style name="LStyled.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/header_background</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenu1</item>
    </style>     <style name="OverflowMenu1" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
    </style>

Comment: what's mistake here for overflowmenu? not able to change background color of overflow menu and items text color. default is dark gray background and white text. i need white background and black text color for overflow menu items

Comment: @MihirShah Let's talk here: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90963/overflow-styling).

Comment: @Vikram height attribute not working for me. Any one have idea how to increase the height of the actionMode?

Answer (score 34):

use **actionModeBackground** in your *AppTheme.Base* style.

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary </item> (or)
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary </item>
```

Comment: Works on both Lollipop and KitKat.

Comment: how to change background color and textcolor of overflow menu items in CAB?

Answer (score 0):

To change the Title Color of contextual action bar this was the only method that worked for me:

Write this in your activity's theme

```xml
<item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ContextualActionModeTheme</item>
```

Define the styles

```xml
<style name="ContextualActionModeTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
       <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/titleColor</item>
</style>
<style name="titleColor" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color_here</item>
</style>
```

The title color of your contextual action bar would be changed.