# tollbar material design change color when setMultiChoiceModeListener

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design

I'm using material design in my app and when I long click in a listview item the primary color material design change to default color (Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar)
How can I impede to change color when I long click the listview item?

Comment: you can find answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458421/how-to-customize-the-contextual-action-bar-using-appcompat-in-material-design