# Copy-Paste options in ActionBar appear totally white

Tags: android

Maybe this is not quite an ActionBar problem but the problem is as follows;

I have an EditText and when you long click on the EditText, text selection options appear on ActionBar's position by default. My problem is that, both the texts and background are white, so they cannot be read. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I tried some possible causes of the problem but nothing helped. For example, I tried to change the theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

However, any theme with the AppCompat results totally white.

Also I changed the project theme in Android Studio's interface as follows:

[image]

However it's still white.

The copy-paste options are there and you can click on them, but how can I make them appear? Another solution on SA suggested manually replacing gray icons. But I believe this is not the usual case in Android and there should be another way. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this : <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Comment: Tried it, they are still white.

Comment: This answer should help you. It worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458421/how-to-customize-the-contextual-action-bar-using-appcompat-in-material-design - it will allow you to style the `Contextual Action Bar`, which is what appears when you select text.

Comment: That worked, thanks :)

Comment: Check [this SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35333993/2715073) works for me.