# How to use light Action Mode with DarkActionBar?

Tags: android, themes, android-actionmode

This is my theme. I am using `DarkActionBar` so that the Title, Back Button, and overflow icon are white instead of black.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

However, when text is selected, the ActionMode / Contextual Action Bar is white text on a 'black' background.

When I remove `.DarkActionBar`, then the contextual action bar switches to black on light gray, which is much more pleasing for this app. So if I'm going that route I'd need to find a different way to make the main action bar to use white foreground.

How do I get a light background / dark foreground on the ActionMode / Contextual Action Bar while still having a light foreground on my main ActionBar?

---

Here is what I tried per Daniel's suggestion in the comments:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionMode</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionMode.TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionMode.TitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionMode.TitleText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately, all I have been able to change is the background. All ActionMode text and icons are still white.

I'm going to use `<item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>` for now. It's better than black background.

Still it seems there would be a way to change the foreground to black allowing me to use Android's typical light-gray background.

Comment: Have you tried setting `actionModeStyle`? Take a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458421/how-to-customize-the-contextual-action-bar-using-appcompat-in-material-design

Comment: @DanielNugent, See my edit.

Comment: Hmm, actually it looks like that should work. Strange...

Comment: Whoops! Forgot to add `actionMenuTextColor` to my `values-v21\styles.xml` override. So, all those attempts at changing the color, only the first one was necessary `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>`. I didn't need `titleTextStyle` etc. Looks like I would have to package clipart icons into my project though because they are still white on white. Seems like Android would have a more direct solution, but maybe not.

Comment: Nice! You should write up an answer with your final configuration.  Note, you can find icons for most things here, in both light and dark options: https://design.google.com/icons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked my way to an answer but its very manual:

It's possible to add all your own graphics for each image in a style for your theme:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!-- Override the ActionMode Style -->
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>

        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close</item>

        <!-- Styles inherited from the Base Theme -->
        <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_content_content_cut</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_content_content_copy</item>
        <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_content_content_paste</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_content_select_all</item>

    </style>
    <!-- Action Mode -->
    <style name="ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>

    </style>

    <!-- Title text of Contextual action bar-->
    <style name="TitleTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Luckily for us Roman Nurik put together a nice tool to get all the assets we need:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60

Just use the clip-art option (search for cut, copy, past, select all, & close)

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. There's a very nice Image Resource from Clipart tool within android Studio, so it wouldn't be that time-consuming. I was just hoping that Android provided a more straight-forward mechanism for this.

Comment: Maybe I should focus on changing the Foreground of the regular Action Bar, so I can remove the `.DarkActionBar` option. That way there are only two images to replace (Back, Overflow), not counting my custom icons. (which are already light foreground anyway)

Comment: Looks like Roman Nurik has more clipart than Android Studio does. :-)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey That is one option or you could use Toolbar only and the tinting options available in styles for that widget