# How change the Contextual Action Bar color programmatically?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I need to change Contextual Action Bar color programmatically. How to do it in the style I know. Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Customize the Contextual Action Bar using appCompat in material design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458421/how-to-customize-the-contextual-action-bar-using-appcompat-in-material-design)

Answer (score -1):

Use the code

```
   getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable( <create a background drawable with solid rectangle and color as what you want>);
```

if you are using support library then try with

```
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(<create a background drawable with solid rectangle and color as what you want>);
```

Comment: This is not for the action mode, just for the actionbar